# How do I apply a color array to a automatic counter

Tags: javascript

I built a stop watch in javascript, I can use CSS to change the color of the counter but I want to the counter change color automatically by pulling from an array of predetermined colors. I know how to fetch random index's but i'm not sure how to apply them to the start timer function. Or if doing an array is the correct way of applying this.

```
window.onload;
let minutes = 00;
let seconds = 00;
let tens = 00;
const roundMinutes = $("#minutes");
const roundTens = $("#tens");
const roundSeconds = $("#seconds");
const buttonStart = document.getElementById("button-start");
const buttonStop = document.getElementById("button-stop");
const buttonReset = document.getElementById("button-reset");
let Interval;
const colors = [
  "Blue",
  "Green",
  "Black",
  "Red",
  "Orange",
  "Yellow",
  "Violet",
  "Indigo",
];

function getRandomItem(colors) {
  // get random index value
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);

  // get random item
  const item = colors[randomIndex];

  return item;
}

buttonStart.onclick = function () {
  clearInterval(Interval);
  Interval = setInterval(startTimer, 10);
};

buttonStop.onclick = function () {
  clearInterval(Interval);
};

buttonReset.onclick = function () {
  clearInterval(Interval);
  minutes = "00";
  tens = "00";
  seconds = "00";
  roundTens.text(tens);
  roundSeconds.text(seconds);
  roundMinutes.text(minutes);
};

function startTimer() {
  tens++;
  
  if (tens <= 9) {
    roundTens.text("0" + tens);
  }

  if (tens > 9) {
    roundTens.text(tens);
  }

  if (tens > 99) {
    console.log("seconds");
    seconds++;
    roundSeconds.text("0" + seconds);
    tens = 0;
    roundTens.text("0" + tens);
  }

  if (seconds > 9) {
    roundSeconds.text(seconds);
  }

  if (seconds > 59) {
    console.log("minutes");
    minutes++;
    roundMinutes.text("0" + minutes);
    seconds = 0;
    roundSeconds.text("0" + seconds);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already created a method to get a random colour from an array, I think an array is the correct way to go about it.

You just have to change the css through js.

For example, you could do:

```js
document.getElementById('stopwatch').style.color = getRandomItem(colors);
```

in whatever function you want the colour to change. Since you want it to be random, I assume that you want to set it on interval. So probably in the `startTimer` function.

The only thing is, names such as "Blue" and "Green" are probably not valid css colour names. Change them to "blue", "green" and so on. Hexadecimals or other formats should work fine as well.